# How to trace menu links not linked to a node in views

Tags: views, files, blocks

I am using **drupal 7.18** + **views 7.x-3.5** + **menu node views 7.x.1**

I managed to make blocks of the children of the active menu item, using views and menu node views based on the menu node id contextual filter. (similar functionality with menu block module but more flexible).

Now i created some menu links that are linked directly to pdf files, so there is no node available.
**Views can identify such menu links (not linked to a node)?**

I just want to have a dynamic list of pdfs, using views accordion module.
Any suggestions on how to do that are appreciated!